# In my Android studio monitor showing on bottom but logcat nothing to show

Tags: android

As showing in this image in my android studio I'm not able to view logcat.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/udHvU.png]

Comment: Its not showing because android studio don't have any connected device.

Comment: connect a device. and turn on developer options. and any app you run can be seen there in the android monitor.

Comment: Device is connected I run my code on it.

Comment: How exactly are you running your code on your device if Android Studio doesn't "see" the device?

Comment: make sure u have connected your device

Comment: Sorry in this screenshot device is not connected but when device is connected I'm not able to view logcat only monitor  is visible

Comment: `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Logcat` (Or something else in `Tool Windows` if you're on Studio 2.x, forget what it was called.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Logcat is most likely in Window mode by itself, detached from Monitor. Best way is to:

1. Reduce size of main Android studio window to smallest (not minimize)
2. Minimize all aps (Win+D)
3. Click on on Android studio in OS taskbar
4. Look for your missing logcat window on screen(s)
5. Drag-and drop logcat window to android monitor, by draging logcat tab

It can be very small, like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just go to on Android Studio

```
View-> Tool Window-> and Click on Logcat
```

or use shortcut on windows Alt+6

Comment: Logcat not found under Tool Window

Comment: not Tool, go through  View (Right of Edit) then ToolWindow